# How do I create a security rules with multiple protocols using Terraform in Azure?

Tags: azure, terraform

My plan is to allow the protocols ICMP and TCP on the same security rule but I'm having problems related the "attribute value typ"

My Terraform code:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "example" {
  name                = "01-tf-SG"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name

  security_rule {
    name                       = "test123"
    priority                   = 100
    direction                  = "Inbound"
    access                     = "Allow"
    protocol                   = **["Icmp", "Tcp"]**  ---> iT FAILS!!! 
    source_port_range          = "*"
    destination_port_range     = "*"
    source_address_prefix      = "172.16.25.10/32"
    destination_address_prefix = "10.0.1.10/32"
  }
```

I didn't find any example in terraform repo: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/network_security_rule

Be able to use multiple protocols on the same security rule protocol field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Mark B` listed in his answer, you cannot provide a list for `protocol`. However you could use a [dynamic block](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) so it would create the two rules without having to define them both individually duplicating the code

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "example" {
  name                = "01-tf-SG"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name

  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = toset(["Icmp", "Tcp"])
    content {
      name                       = "test123"
      priority                   = 100
      direction                  = "Inbound"
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = security_rule.value
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "*"
      source_address_prefix      = "172.16.25.10/32"
      destination_address_prefix = "10.0.1.10/32"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @chris Doyle. Your solution is the most efficient.

Just note that you forgot the **[ ]** into toset function. So the final code would be:

```html
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "example" {
  name                = "01-tf-SG"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.main.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name

  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = toset(["Icmp", "Tcp"])
    content {
      name                       = "test123"
      priority                   = 100
      direction                  = "Inbound"
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = security_rule.value
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "*"
      source_address_prefix      = "172.16.25.10/32"
      destination_address_prefix = "10.0.1.10/32"
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```html
# azurerm_network_security_group.example will be created
  + resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "example" {
      + id                  = (known after apply)
      + location            = "westeurope"
      + name                = "01-tf-SG"
      + resource_group_name = "RG_AZ_Terraform"
      + security_rule       = [
          + {
              + access                                     = "Allow"
              + description                                = ""
              + destination_address_prefix                 = "10.0.1.10/32"
              + destination_address_prefixes               = []
              + destination_application_security_group_ids = []
              + destination_port_range                     = "*"
              + destination_port_ranges                    = []
              + direction                                  = "Inbound"
              + name                                       = "test123"
              + priority                                   = 100
              + protocol                                   = "Icmp"
              + source_address_prefix                      = "172.16.25.10/32"
              + source_address_prefixes                    = []
              + source_application_security_group_ids      = []
              + source_port_range                          = "*"
              + source_port_ranges                         = []
            },
          + {
              + access                                     = "Allow"
              + description                                = ""
              + destination_address_prefix                 = "10.0.1.10/32"
              + destination_address_prefixes               = []
              + destination_application_security_group_ids = []
              + destination_port_range                     = "*"
              + destination_port_ranges                    = []
              + direction                                  = "Inbound"
              + name                                       = "test123"
              + priority                                   = 100
              + protocol                                   = "Tcp"
              + source_address_prefix                      = "172.16.25.10/32"
              + source_address_prefixes                    = []
              + source_application_security_group_ids      = []
              + source_port_range                          = "*"
              + source_port_ranges                         = []
            },
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Ah yeah sorry. I didn't test this just wrote it by hand. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol attribute [doesn't accept a list](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/network_security_group). You would either need to create two security rules, or use `*` for the protocol.